# How to determine position size?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis

I have been trading on a demo account for a few months now, with consistent profits. And then consistent losses. I take position sizes based on how much I like the trade, and I am almost sure this is my pitfall, (E.G. I make 100 dollars each on 5 trades, then subjectively allocate 5 times more to a trade I am sure of (this is what I need help with), then my (well-placed) stop-loss is hit, and I lose $450). I have fine risk management. In my mission to create an objective system, I have researched a few strategies to determine position size:

1. INDICATOR: Creating a position size-based on my stop-loss level, limiting the amount of capital at risk by changing my position size. This method is the one that I hear the most about (the 1-2% rule). PROBLEM: This is nice, but it has serious problems. It doesn't let me allocate more money to trades that are more likely to go in my favor, and it doesn't change based on volatility.
2. INDICATOR: Using the ATR of the stock (ATR/Close)%*(*x*), use this percent as the amount of capital to risk. PROBLEM: There are multiple, first, the *x* value is not something I have discovered accurately. Second, this sometimes makes outrageous results (more than my available capital).
3. INDICATOR: Always use 7-10% of my capital. PROBLEM: Obviously, it does not change based on the strength of the signal, and it doesn't change based on volatility. It is very simple, but not optimal.

---

### Is there a way to determine position size that can rely on the strength of the signal, the volatility of the security, AND doesn't weigh things too differently?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question.  I'd guess that if you are allocating more money to trades that are more likely to go in your favor and it's not working out, then your assessment of the trade potential is off.  What I do know is that net gains occur when you make more than you lose and that occurs from having  more winners than losers and/or more big winners and fewer big losers.  AFAIC, risk management is the important consideration.

Comment: You did not read the question very closely, I am winning and my risk management (other than position size) is fine. It's just that when my stop is hit, for a security, the trades that I have subjectively allocated more capital to, lose more than the rest gain. E.G. I make 100 dollars each on 5 trades, then subjectively allocate 5 times more to a trade I am sure of (this is what I need help with), then my (well-placed) stop-loss is hit, and I lose $450.

Comment: As I said, I'd guess that if you are allocating more money to trades that are more likely to go in your favor and it's not working out, then your assessment of the trade potential is off.  Keep position size consistent and make 100 dollars each on 5 trades and then lose $90 once instead of $450.

Comment: OK, just answer that... But I do have good judgment: I do allocate more to some trades subjectively correctly. And that is what I want to change. I want to find a better system than 1:1.5 RR